# Querying Firestore database with URL params

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm trying to get *plants* that have a folderId with value based on the `useRouter` params. I don't have errors but no data is returned and I do have *plants* with folderId in "PlantsData" `collection`. Code:

```
const [user] = useAuthState(auth)

const {
  query: { id },
} = useRouter();

const [plants, setPlants] = useState();
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

const getPlants= async () => {

  try {

    const PlantsQuery = query(
      collection(db, "PlantsData"),
      where("folderId", "==", id),
      orderBy("postedAt", "desc")
    );

    const plantsDocs = await getDocs(PlantsQuery);
    const plants = plantsDocs.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
    }));

    setPlants((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      plants: plants,
    }));

    setLoading(false);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error.message);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (id && user) {
    getPlants();
  }
}, [id, user]);
```

Comment: Your code to query the database looks fine at first glance. Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of the Firebase console a document that you expect the query to return?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did figure it out, used `where(new FieldPath("folder", "folderId"), "==", id)` - `folder` is the object field `folderId` was in and thats why it didn't work I think.

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem.   You can also use dot-notation in that case, so `where("folder.folderId"), "==", id)`

Answer (score 0):

`folderId` was in an object field `folder` and did fix it by: `where(new FieldPath("folder", "folderId"), "==", id)`